# C: write (and then read) a string to file using a hash function to locate the byte's position

Tags: c, hash, io

I want to write up to 1KB into a file, and I want to use a hash function to calculate the position of the byte I'm going to write. Obviously I also want to be able later to retrieve the data in the correct order.

To locate the position of the byte to read/write I use the hash function

```
f = (index*prime) mod 1024
```

where index is the index in the string, and prime is a prime number that I need to avoid collisions, i.e. not rewriting two times in the same position.
f, strlen (b
First I create the file

```
dd bs=1024 count=1 if=/dev/zero of=test.fs
```

and after that I compile and run my program passing "w" as parameter

```
$ ./a.out w
```

Now, it seems to me that the write() function does its job correctly, because if I do...

```
$ cat test.fs
or
$ hexdump test.fs
```

... I can see the content of the file is consistent with the string I inserted!

However, if I run it into read-mode by passing "r" as parameter, I get always a curious random output, it seems to me like if I'm reading thrash from memory. I cannot understand where the read() function fails, thank you in advance.

The C code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PRIME 7919

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int mode;

        if (argc < 2)
                return 1;
        else if (strcmp (argv[1], "r") == 0)
                mode = 1;
        else if (strcmp (argv[1], "w") == 0)
                mode = 2;
        else
                return 1;


        FILE *fs;
        char buf[1024];
        int val;
        int i;
        char c;

        if (mode == 1) {
                fs = fopen("test.fs", "rb");
                val = read (buf, 1024, fs);
                if (val != 1024)
                        fprintf(stderr, "Either an error occurred, or the EOF was reached.\n");
                printf("Content read: %s\n", buf);
        }
        else if (mode == 2) {
                fs = fopen("test.fs", "wb");
                printf ("Enter a string you want write to disk: ");
                while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
                        buf[i++] = c;
                buf[i] = EOF;

                val = write (fs, buf, strlen (buf));
                if (val == EOF)
                        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred while writing.\n");
                printf("%d bytes written to disk.\n");
        }

        fclose (fs);
}


int write(FILE *f, char *str, long len)
{
        int i;
        int err;
        for (i=0; i < len && err != EOF; i++) {
                fseek(f, (i*PRIME)%1024, SEEK_SET);
                err = fputc(str[i], f);
        }
        if (err != EOF)
                return i;
        else
                return EOF;
}


int read(char *buffer, long len, FILE *f)
{
        int i;
        int br = 1;
        for (i=0; i < len && br != 0; i++) {
                fseek(f, (i*PRIME)%1024, SEEK_SET);
                br = fread (&buffer[i],1,1,f);
        }
        if (ferror (f))
                return EOF;
        else
                return i;
}
```

Comment: 'if' is a reserved word in C, suggest you change it to something else.  I would expect the compiler to have caught that problem and issued a warning/error.  (you do have all the warnings enabled when compiling, yes?)

Comment: the returned values from fseek, fopen, fread, fwrite, fputc, fgetc need to be checked to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: EOF is not a valid terminator for a string in the buf[] so this line: buf[i] = EOF; should be: buf[i] = '\0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer` is not a string, it is an array of characters. When you incorrectly print it as a string:

```
printf("Content read: %s\n", buf);
```

you get a buffer overflow since your array isn't null terminated.